# Exclude rows from excel autofilter

Tags: excel

Is it possible to exclude rows from Excel's autofilter? For example, if I have a column with numbers and blank cells, the blanks should always display regardless of the number chosen.

Comment: When you apply the autofilter, there should be a tickbox to include Blanks along with the set of unique numbers in the column.

Comment: Do you mean you always want it done automatically? I can see the problem if you use the search box and type in what number you want, then the blanks go away and it's hard to get them in (in an easy way). Is that the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include blanks in the Dialog Box.  Starting with:

[image]

Do something like:

[image]

Comment: I was trying to be too complicated. Thanks.